# Aplicar máscara ao digitar no campo input, ao digitar um numero mostrar asterisco invez de números ou letras

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

como faço para aplicar máscara no campo input, quando o usuário for digitar ao invés de aparecer os números/letras eu quero que apareça nesse campo input o caracteres especiais (*). Exemplo: 999******99.

Comment: O `input type password` não resolveria seu caso ?

Comment: Não porque quando o usuário for digitar ele irá completar com asterisco, eu preciso que quando ele digitar irá aparecer número + asterisco + número.

Answer (score 0):

Achei essa resposta no SOEN (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113132/partial-password-masking-on-input-field). Podes adaptar a sua realidade, ela faz praticamente o que você quer.

```js
 var ssn = document.getElementById('ssn');
    ssn.addEventListener('input', ssnMask, false);
    var ssnFirstFive = "";
    var secondHalf = "";
    var fullSSN = "";

    function ssnMask(){
        if (ssn.value.length <= 5){
            ssn.type = 'password';
        }
        else{
            detectChanges();
            secondHalf = ssn.value.substring(5);
            ssn.type = 'text';
            ssn.value = "•••••";
            ssn.value += secondHalf;
            fullSSN = ssnFirstFive + secondHalf;
        }
    }

    function detectChanges() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (ssn.value[i] != "•"){
                ssnFirstFive = ssnFirstFive.substring(0, i) + ssn.value[i] + ssnFirstFive.substring(i+1);
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="password" id="ssn" maxlength=9 />
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou implementar essa solução no meu formulário, era isso mesmo que estava precisando. vlwwww

Comment: Aceite a resposta então como resolvida. :)